# Passing arrays via query string in wordpress

Tags: arrays, wordpress, get

I'm building an application using a significant amount of custom PHP running on top of Wordpress in which I pass arrays over via GET query parameters.  The query strings I generate look like this:

http://mydomain.com/locations.php?filters&f[184]=1&f[197]=1&f[235]=1&f[912]=1&setPage=1

Unfortunately, wordpress strips the [ and ] from the query string leaving this:

/locations.php?filters&f184=1&f197=1&f235=1&f912=1&setPage=1

Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php.

In javascript, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp

Comment: Thanks.  I've always used urlencode on the values of query string parameters but never thought to use it on the parameter name itself.  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Use `http_build_query( $args )` to build your URL.